# Live wallpaper selection on Pie?

Tags: 9.0-pie, live-wallpaper

I find the new Wallpaper app on Pie doesn't let you pick live wallpapers. Even [when I downloaded the APK](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/live-wallpaper-picker/live-wallpaper-picker-9-release/live-wallpaper-picker-9-2-android-apk-download/) and installed it, it says 'cannot install'.

It's not as though 9 doesn't support them, the first time I installed a live wallpaper, I was able to click 'open' on the package installer and set it, but now since it doesn't provide an app icon I can't go back to it if I change to something else. I'm running the LineageOS 16 based [Resurrection Remix](https://www.resurrectionremix.com/) custom ROM on a OnePlus 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overkill - I had to install the [Pixel 3 live wallpaper collection](https://www.xda-developers.com/download-google-pixel-3-live-wallpapers-port/) that weighs in at 159 MB. It lets me choose my own live wallpapers in addition to the built in ones (that made it so bloated).

I've marked this as the answer - but open to other alternatives too.

Answer (score 0):

You should install a third-party launcher for your Android phone. This will enable you choose Live wallpapers. Your custom ROM launcher doesn't support live wallpapers.

Also, for future references, contact the developers of the custom ROM to include the ability to include live wallpaper option in their next versions.

Comment: Live wallpaper depends on the wallpaper selection app, not the launcher. If you paid attention to my post, I clearly said I am able to set a live wallpaper if I open the wallpaper app (not the wallpaper selector) right after I install it. Since it doesn't add a launcher icon, I can't open it again. The current wallpaper selector is directly taken from Google with no changes, and it only shows a few built-in wallpapers (presumably from Pixel) and my gallery pictures.

Comment: Please check here for "APK not installed" error: https://www.digitbin.com/app-not-installed-fix-error/

Comment: I paid attention to your post. Wallpaper apps don't add a launcher icon. Have you tried any other wallpaper pickers? I have had luck working with wallpaper apps like Wallzy which themselves integrate a wallpaper picker service with Live wallpaper option. Also, launchers have a wallpaper picking service within themselves and that's why I recommended doing an install.

Comment: I'd just like the default functionality back - I don't get why adding the stock live wallpaper picker for 9 doesn't work. Did you mean this - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phpmalik.wallzy ? Looks like a frontend for Unsplashed, which has its own app. Can it specifically let you set live wallpapers that you already have installed? I'm not interested in whatever downloads they offer.